# importing struct with trait from lib

Tags: rust

Just wondering if there is a difference between importing from a module and importing from a library.

Can someone run the following code and tell me what I am missing

```
pub trait PersonDetails {
    fn name(&self) -> String;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub age: u32
}

impl PersonDetails for Person {
    fn name(&self) -> String {
        format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name)
    }
}
```

putting the above in a normal file works perfectly.

The problem is when I put it into a lib and try importing Person and then running name function as so

```
let person = Person{ first_name: "fname".to_string(), last_name: "lname".to_string(), age: 32};
println!("{:?}", person.name());
```

I created a lib called broker and inside lib.rs I put the trait and struct, imported it into my main project and tried to use it.

When I import it into the main project, I get the following error

[image: rust trait error]

Any help and explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "I imported it" is unnecessarily vague, when the exact code you used could be provided just as easily.

Comment: You guys are pretty awesome. Works well now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully you will notice that it says "items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope". That means that to use `name(&self)` you must import `PersonDetails` into the module. Your code works on your original crate because you declared the trait in that scope.